# Can't color pick from external backgrounds in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs5, color-profile

Experiencing some weird behaviour in Photoshop CS5 on a Mac (Mavericks). I've tried resetting all tools, restarting Photoshop and made sure the image is RGB mode (8-bit) but the color picker won't color-pick correctly from external images, websites, pdfs etc.

It works ok within the current document i.e. I can color pick from the layers in my Photoshop document fine, just not elements outside of Photoshop. It was working before, so not sure what's happened. Here's a video of the behaviour:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zqPERGEusc

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Osu

Comment: I think you have to select the layer that you want to pick the color.

Comment: Maybe your Eyedropper `Sample size` is anything but point sample. [Image of the eyedropper settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTQOJ.png)

Comment: Click **inside** the Photoshop document, then drag the cursor off the document to pick a color. Note: this also tends to fail if you are using multiple monitors. **Photoshop likes to pick color from the primary monitor** only.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, but unfortunately, I tried all those and it doesn't seems to work. @Scott - I'm using just a laptop so I assume I shouldn't have issues with multiple monitors. Anything else I can try? What's strange is that random colors seem to be being picked when I try to color pick outside of the Photoshop doc...

Comment: Trash prefs.. etc. Standard troubleshooting at that point.